# How i pass the data from windows popup to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have create a popup windows called AddCust.cshtml. Once the user clicked btnSaveConsumer it should picked up all value entered. But i am not sure how to pass the controller. I tried to used the javascript like the following but it not passing anything from AddCust.cshtml. Please advise, Thank you

**AddCust.cshtml**

```
@model HHIMS_Web_App.Models.ConsumerModel
@{

}

<br />
<div>

<fieldset id="AddNewConsumer">


                      <br /> <br />
        <div>
            <div class="addConsumerInfo">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HRN)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HRN)
            </div>

            <div class="smallBox">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)

            </div>

        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="addConsumerInfo">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GivenName1)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GivenName1)

            </div>

        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="addConsumerInfo">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FamilyName1)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FamilyName1)
            </div>
            <div class="smallBox">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ethnicity)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ethnicity)

            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="addConsumerInfo">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GivenName2)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GivenName2)

            </div>

        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="addConsumerInfo">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FamilyName2)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FamilyName2)
            </div>

        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="addConsumerInfo">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)

            </div>

            <div class="smallBox">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarerContactName)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CarerContactName)

            </div>

        </div>



        <div>
            <div class="addConsumerInfo">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Community)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Community)

            </div>
            <div class="smallBox">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarerContact)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CarerContact)

            </div>


        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="addConsumerInfo">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)

            </div>


        </div>

        <div>
             <div class="addConsumerInfo">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostCode)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostCode)
             </div>

        </div>

        <div>
             <div class="addConsumerInfo">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
             </div>
             <div class="smallAddAndCancel">
                <input type="button" id="btnCancel" style="height:33px; width:70px; font-size:14px; background-color:#3399FF" class="k-button" title="Cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="window.close()" />
                <input type="button" id="btnSaveConsumer" style="height:33px; width:70px; font-size:14px; background-color:#3399FF" class="k-button" title="Save" value="Save" />

            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">



    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#btnSaveConsumer').click(function () {

            var hrn;
            var community;
            var ethnicity;
            var familyName;
            var givenName;

            if (hrn) {
                $filter.push({ field: "HRN", operator: "contains", value: hrn });
            }

            if (community) {
                $filter.push({ field: "Community", operator: "contains", value: community });
            }

            if (familyName) {
                $filter.push({ field: "FamilyName", operator: "contains", value: familyName });
            }

            if (givenName) {
                $filter.push({ field: "GivenName", operator: "contains", value: givenName });
            }

            if (ethnicity) {
                $filter.push({ field: "Ethnicity", operator: "contains", value: ethnicity });
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "@(Url.Content("~/ConsumerDetails/CreateConsumerList/"))",
                data: {
                        "HRN": hrn,
                        "Community":community,
                        "FamilyName1":familyName,
                        "GivenName1":givenName,
                        "Ethnicity":ethnicity,

                },

            });
        });


    });

</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateConsumerList(ConsumerModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                HHIMS_DataAccessLayer.Consumers dalModel = new HH.Consumers();
                Mapper.CreateMap<ConsumerModel, HH.Consumers>();
                Mapper.Map(model, dalModel);

                dbConsumer.SaveConsumer(dalModel);

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it more simple by encapsulating all your fields in a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action","contoroller")) {
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HRN)
}
```

then submit your form

```
var $form = $("#the_id_of_the_form");
// want to validate your form?
// $form.validate();
// if (!$form.valid()) return;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "@Url.Action("CreateConsumerList","ConsumerDetails")",
    data: $form.serialize(),            
});
```

Or if you do not want to use a form for what ever reason:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Action("CreateConsumerList","ConsumerDetails")",
        data: {
            HRN: $("#HRN").val()
            // do the same for the rest of the fields
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript for this. You are adding more work by collecting form filed values in .click event and calling `$.ajax` function. I feel this as an extra step. I would suggest using `AjaxHelper`

```
@model HHIMS_Web_App.Models.ConsumerModel

    @using(Ajax.BeginForm("CreateConsumerList", "ControllerName",new AjaxOptions {Success:, HttpMethod = "Post" }))
    {
    <div>
       <fieldset id="AddNewConsumer">
// All your form fields here
<div class="smallAddAndCancel">
                <input type="button" id="btnCancel" style="height:33px; width:70px; font-size:14px; background-color:#3399FF" class="k-button" title="Cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="window.close()" />
                <input type="submit" id="btnSaveConsumer" style="height:33px; width:70px; font-size:14px; background-color:#3399FF" class="k-button" title="Save" value="Save" />

            </div>
     </fieldset>

    </div>
    }
```

Comment: "You don't need JavaScript" and yet you are using ajax ;)

Comment: I meant $.ajax calls. that's an extra step. why don't he make use of MVC framkework fully with System.Web.Mvc.Ajax

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer, that's a better content. Now about "all unnecessary", that's called "preference". Using the `AjaxHelper` is not the best way to go, especially on a large project where you have UI guys who are excellent jquery devs and CSS experts. And the requirements is you have to have UIs that are clean of server side codes. Have you encountered a project where it will tell you to use a form tag than use `using`? I know right. So bottom line, it's a preference and "unnecessary" is not the best term to use ;)

Comment: @vonv. thanks for suggesting. I will replace the term with some lighter word.